# MYSQL Query to get all results where one column happens more than once in different groups and matches certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Let's say I have the following data:

```
object    size    color    units
------    ----    -----    -----
ball      small   red      3
ball      small   red      2
ball      medium  blue     2
ball      medium  blue     1
ball      big     yellow   2
hat       big     green    3
hat       big     green    4
umbrella  medium  blue     1
umbrella  medium  blue     4
umbrella  big     blue     4
umbrella  huge    red      2
umbrella  huge    green    1
book      small   white    4
book      small   brown    3
book      medium  brown    2
```

I need a query that returns all object-color-size variations for all objects for which at least one of the variation's total units for that size and color is at least 5, so the query would return these rows:

```
object    size    color    total_units
------    ----    -----    ------
ball      small   red      5
ball      medium  blue     3
ball      big     yellow   2
umbrella  medium  blue     5
umbrella  big     blue     4
umbrella  huge    red      2
umbrella  huge    green    1
```

The reason why all the balls and their totals per size-color variation appear in the results, is because there is at least 2 different balls and the total units of at least one of them is 5 or more

The reason why all the umbrellas and their totals per size-color variation appear in the results, is because there is at least 2 different umbrellas and the total units of at least one of them is 5 or more

The reason why the hat does not appear in the results is because eventhough there are more than 5 units(7) of the big-green hat, there is NOT at least 2 different hats

The reason why none of the books appear in the results is because even though there are 3 different books, there isn't at least 5 units of any of them.

Thank you for showing me how this can be accomplished!

Comment: It isn't clear why `ball  medium  blue` appears in the output.  Neither the sum of the total units, nor any individual unit, is greater than or equal to 5.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I thought I had clarified that when I said "The reason why all the balls and their totals per size-color variation appear in the results, is because there is at least 2 different balls and the total units of at least one of them is 5 or more". Let me know if you still need clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using window functions (in the most recent versions of MySQL and MariaDB databases), this is easy:

```
select object, size, color, total_units
from (select object, size, color, sum(units) as total_units,
             max(sum(units)) over (partition by object) as max_total_units,
             count(*) over (partition by object) as cnt
      from t
      group by object, size, color
     ) t
where max_total_units >= 5 and cnt > 1;
```

Comment: NOTE: I tested both this answer and the one from @Madhur Bhaiya with my real life table and data and both showed almost identical execution speed. I was just forced to choose one correct answer, so I chose the one that seemed a bit shorter in syntax. Thank you so much to both!

Answer (score 1):

- In a Derived Table, we can identify the unique `Object` values, which has atleast more than 1 combination, as well as one of the combinations have atleast total 5 units.
- Join back to the main table to get only those rows (post `GROUP BY`).

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  t.object, t.size, t.color, SUM(t.units) AS total_units 
FROM 
your_table AS t
JOIN 
(
  SELECT dt.object 
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      object, size, color, SUM(units) AS total_units 
    FROM your_table 
    GROUP BY 
      object, size, color
  ) AS dt 
  GROUP BY dt.object 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND 
         SUM(dt.total_units >= 5) /* atleast one with 5 units */
) AS dt2 
  ON dt2.object = t.object
GROUP BY t.object, t.size, t.color;
```

**Result**

```
| object   | size   | color  | total_units |
| -------- | ------ | ------ | ----------- |
| ball     | big    | yellow | 2           |
| ball     | medium | blue   | 3           |
| ball     | small  | red    | 5           |
| umbrella | big    | blue   | 4           |
| umbrella | huge   | green  | 1           |
| umbrella | huge   | red    | 2           |
| umbrella | medium | blue   | 5           |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cRthbcfAUwLeCukWbxne5W/0)

Comment: thanks @Madhur Bhaiya. Your query works, if you correct the little typo in which instead of "SUM(dt.total_units = 5)" it should say "SUM(dt.total_units >= 5)"